# probability of a collision on a n bit secure hash.

Tags: probability

I have a homework question that I need confirmation on.

Wikipedia states that a hash of n bits can be broken in $2^{n/2}$.  Meaning that $2^{n/2}$ of hashes is expected to be computed in order to find a collision.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack

I've got 2 questions.

1. (Part of the homework question)  If it takes $2^{n/2}$ calculation to create a collision, will it take $10*2^{n/2}$ calculations to find 10 collisions?  Is my assumption correct?
2. (Not part of the homework), how did they calculate $2^{n/2}$?  I know it's similar to the birthday problem, but I still don't understand how they got that value.

Comment: Did you read this one too: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack  ? Also Intuitively I would expect 10 collisions not to take 10 times longer because you have already generated many distinct hashes by the time you have found 1.

Comment: Yeah I've read the birthday problem.  Your right, I didn't take the hashes that was already created into account.  So would it be 2^n/2+10??

Comment: Probably more than that, would have to understand how they got the first figure. In the link they have a few derivations and approximations. what part are you getting stuck at?

Comment: whats 1.25 square root of H.  Where did they get that from?  Also where did they get that initial equation p(n;H).  The article makes a lot of assumptions but does not show how these things were derived.

Comment: What I derived from the birthday problem and other sources, I got 1-(2^n!)/((2^n-2)!*2^2n), but how does that give me 2^n/2?